# erro ao criar tabela com foreign key mysql

Tags: php, mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Está dando um erro `Can't create table` ao criar esta tabela no MySql. Não faço idéia de onde esteja o problema D:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbnoticiasrel` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_noticia` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`id_noticia_relacionada` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 FOREIGN KEY fk_id_noticia(`id_noticia`) 
 REFERENCES tbnews(`id`),
 FOREIGN KEY fk_id_noticia_relacionada(`id_noticia_relacionada`) ,
 REFERENCES tbnews(`id`)
 )
```

Comment: você já tem a tabela fk_id_noticia_relacionada criada?

Comment: Tente `FOREIGN KEY (\`id_noticia\`) REFERENCES ...`  sem o nome da FK.

Comment: o fk_id_noticia_relacionada é o nome que eu to dando pra minha FK -

Comment: Qual mensagem de erro o banco mostra pra você?

Comment: deu o mesmo erro dessa maneira KaduAmaral

Comment: mostra Cant' create table 'nomedoesquema'.'nomedatabela' (errno: 150)

Comment: coloca `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` na linha antes do `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbnoticiasrel` com isso ele não vai verificar as `FOREIGN KEY`

Comment: com esse SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; funcionou, valeu (:

Comment: @EstácioDiFabio tentou executar o código sem a `virgula` que mencionei? Esse `SET FOREING_KEY...` parece ser uma [_Solução Alternativa_](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambiarra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

coloca SET `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` na linha antes do `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbnoticiasrel` com isso ele não vai verificar as `FOREIGN KEY`

Answer (score 1):

O problema é na sintaxe da segunda FK, tem uma virgula entre a FK e a Referência:

```
 FOREIGN KEY fk_id_noticia(`id_noticia`) 
 REFERENCES tbnews(`id`),
 FOREIGN KEY fk_id_noticia_relacionada(`id_noticia_relacionada`) ,
 REFERENCES tbnews(`id`)
```

Apenas remova-a:

```
 FOREIGN KEY fk_id_noticia(`id_noticia`) 
 REFERENCES tbnews(`id`),
 FOREIGN KEY fk_id_noticia_relacionada(`id_noticia_relacionada`)
 REFERENCES tbnews(`id`)
```

Comment: ba nem tinha visto essa virgula D:

Answer (score 0):

Sempre que você for criar uma tabela referenciada para um banco de dados "com dados", por padrão, o MySQL, faz uma verificação dos índices referenciados, quando ele não encontra a referência dentro da tabela  costuma dar esse tipo de problema, para resolver isso de forma que não precise utilizar o `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`, cujo o comando serve para bloquear a reindexação das chaves estrageiras, faça um backup dos dados das tabelas referenciadas criando uma cópia com um *underline*, por exemplo, no final da sua tabela _backup, depois, nas tabelas originais, apague todos os dados, crie a tabela nova que faz a referência e reimporte os dados destas tabelas_backup para as tabelas originais, dessa maneira todo o conteúdo será reindexado, para que não haja futuros conflitos que possa travar seu sistema.